# Auto logout using sessions in Django (outside views)

Tags: django

I'm trying to build a auto-logout function in a Django application.

Basically, with each request to the site I want to set the current timestamp in the session (if not set), and then checking that value with the current time. If the difference is too great, it should redirect to logout.

Is there a easy way to set the session on each request without adding a function to each of my views? 
I know it's possible to use sessions outside views, but then I have to supply the session_key, and I'm not sure where I should get it from, or generate it myself.

Comment: Try the solution here for checking on activity while hitting the databse as little as possible. http://django-session-security.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure what timestamp you are comparing with what here, or why.

The usual way to manage auto-logout is to simply set a short expiry on the session cookie, via the [`SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#session-cookie-age) setting. If the cookie expires, the user will automatically be redirected to the login page if they try and access a page that requires authentication.

Comment: I only want to do logout if the user has been inactive. For example, log the user out after 2 minutes of inactivity. This timer should be reset with each request(hence the timestamp).

Comment: Yes, that is what happens automatically.

Comment: I found a middleware class that does exactly what I need..http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/449/ Thanks for your response though

Comment: @DanielRoseman No it does not, at least not for me. The session's lifetime is not extended when a new request happens. I set SESSION_COOKIE_AGE to 30 minutes, and it destroys the cookie every 30 minutes.